# How to scale plane 2d with bmesh and floatproperty in ui?

Tags: python, transforms, properties, bmesh, scale

THe classic method of scale 2d object is like to

```
###some script to configure ob data bmesh etc.
pivot = Vector(0.5,0.5)
scale_factor = 0.9 decrease scale example

for v in bm.verts:
    v.co -= pivot
    v.co.x *= scale_factor
    v.co.y *= scale_factor
    v.co += pivot
```

but i whant controll the scale with floatproperty in ui panel like to

```
pivot = Vector(0.5,0.5)
scale_factor = my_float_property

for v in bm.verts:
    v.co -= pivot
    v.co.x *= scale_factor
    v.co.y *= scale_factor
    v.co += pivot
```

Clearly this cannot work, I tried to declare a previous value in another floatproperty, so I tried:

```
def myfunction(self,context):
    custom = bpy.context.object.mycustomclass

    pivot = Vector(0.5,0.5)
    scale_factor = 1- (custom.my_float_property-custom.last_float)

    for v in bm.verts:
        v.co -= pivot
        v.co.x *= scale_factor
        v.co.y *= scale_factor
        v.co += pivot

    custom.last_float = custom.my_float_property
```

but have some problem,it is not accurate.

Any idea how to control the scale with a slider, in fact (my_float_property)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a setter getter on the property**

[image]

Can keep the previous value of a property using the custom property `ob["scale_factor"]` to store the previous value.

Warning will cause an issue if you hit exactly 0.0, which may need to be handled in some way.

```
import bpy

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    ob = context.object
    layout.prop(ob, "scale_factor")

def set_float(self, value):
    prev_sf = self.get("scale_factor", 1)
    sf = value / prev_sf
    self.scale.xy *= sf
    self["scale_factor"] = value


def get_float(self):
    return self.get("scale_factor", 1)        

def register():
    bpy.types.Object.scale_factor = bpy.props.FloatProperty(get=get_float, set=set_float)
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(draw)

def unregister():
    pass
    # TODO

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I have done the scaling on an object level here. For a mesh could use `bmesh` and

```
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, 
        vec=(sf, sf, 1),
        space=Matrix.Translation(-pp), # pivot point (x, y, 0)
        verts=bm.verts)
```

or simply make the scale and translation matrices and

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
pp = Vector((1, 1, 0))
sf = 2
me = bpy.context.object.data

Sxy = Matrix.Scale(sf, 4, (1, 0, 0)) @ Matrix.Scale(sf, 4, (0, 1, 0))

me.transform(Matrix.Translation(-pp))
me.transform(Sxy)
me.transform(Matrix.Translation(pp))
```

Comment: Your script works beautifully, thanks!